# Do the keys in AES determine the S and P boxes?

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I once read somewhere that the keys determine the S and P boxes. If so, how does that work?

Comment: Commenting not answering b/c I'm not sure if I recall correctly.  My recollection is that with AES (per your question), the substitution and permutation operations are **not** key-dependent.  However, with some ciphers (e.g. Blowfish), the operations do depend on the key.

Comment: Where did you read that the keys determine the S and P boxes for AES? Considering that AES does not have a P-box as such, the source is suspect.

Comment: I think I was mistaking with blowfish then...but if the substitution-permutation boxes are fixed, then anybody can reverse the encryption process right? Now I know if this was true then it wasn't the standard for the government, but still, if they're fixed, how?

Comment: Have you read the definition of AES, specifically what the steps involved in it are?

Comment: @Ella Rose no..but they have to be key independent right? Cuz if they're fixed then anybody can reverse the ciphertext right?

Comment: @ÖmerEnesÖzmen Your questions are easily answered by simply familiarizing yourself with the design of AES. It's not complicated, there are really only a handful of steps, and one of those steps provides an answer to your question